# If there's a variable in an output is there a way to bring it into use?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, output

Out of this Pandas table, I did some work.

```
   england     best       six      euros
0   kane      grealish  sancho     sterling
1   foden     mount     bellingham reece
2   trippier stones     walker     coady
```

Here's my code:

```
for i in range(0, 3):
    for g in range(1, 4):
        if i+1==g:
            a = f'''r{g} = {list(df.iloc[i])}'''
            print(a)
```

My Output:

```
r1 = ['kane', 'grealish', 'sancho', 'sterling']
r2 = ['foden', 'mount', 'bellingham', 'reece']
r3 = ['trippier', 'stones', 'walker', 'coady']
```

I've got three variables as an output, but is there a way to get them into local use?
Like, `print(r1)` should give me `['kane', 'grealish', 'sancho', 'sterling']`

Is there a way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dictionary, with keys `"r1"`, `"r2"`, etc. For example:

```py
d = {"r{}".format(i): v for i, v in enumerate(df.apply(list, 1), 1)}
print(d)
```

Prints:

```py
{'r1': ['kane', 'grealish', 'sancho', 'sterling'], 
 'r2': ['foden', 'mount', 'bellingham', 'reece'], 
 'r3': ['trippier', 'stones', 'walker', 'coady']}
```

---

```py
print(d["r1"])
```

Prints:

```py
['kane', 'grealish', 'sancho', 'sterling']
```

---

Also, to print row 0 as a list you can use directly `.loc`:

```py
print(df.loc[0, :].tolist())
```

Prints:

```py
['kane', 'grealish', 'sancho', 'sterling']
```

Comment: That's awesome, thanks! I never was a dict fan, so I always looked around for loopholes. I'm a fanboy now

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dictionary like @Andrej has suggested or convert your data frame to a list, then access each row by index. It's not a  good practice to create dynamic variables `r1, r2, r3` in global namespace since it will pollute your namespace and also make those variables difficult to manage:

```
lst = df.values.tolist()
lst[0]
# ['kane', 'grealish', 'sancho', 'sterling']

lst[1]
# ['foden', 'mount', 'bellingham', 'reece']

lst[2]
# ['trippier', 'stones', 'walker', 'coady']
```

Comment: This works too, I didn't know of ```df.values.tolist()```